# Condition Setting of Playbook Vars in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I desire to do something like:

```
vars:
    foo: 'bar'
    bar: 'foo'
    foo_bar: if '{{ foobar }}' == "bar" then "baz" else "zap
```

But for the life of me I can't figure out the jinja template to do so. I also want the ability for the user to assign to `foo_bar` on the command line with `--extra-vars`.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution found was to use a dictionary with a default like so:

```
vars:
    foo: 'bar'
    bar: 'foo'
    foo_bar_dict:
        bar: 'baz'
    foo_bar: "{{ foo_bar_dict[foobar] | default('zap') }}"
```

Now, if `foobar == 'baz'` it get the correct result, and if it doesn't we default (else) to "zap". Finally, if I override it on the command line `--extra-vars "foo_bar=zip" then that overrides every thing and`foo_bar == zip`.